# apt-get version of tmux is old

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, tmux

I used apt-get to install tmux and after doing so `tmux -V` returned 1.6, which is an older version. According to the [tmux web site](https://tmux.github.io/), the current version is 2.2. This is a problem because I would like to have the `z` command to zoom my window which is only in version 1.8 or later.

Why is apt-get delivering such an old version of tmux? Do I have to download and install 2.2 manually to update my version or is there a way to use apt-get to get a later version automatically?

Comment: is there a good reason why you haven't upgraded to Debian 8 aka "jessie"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different releases of Debian have different versions of `tmux`.  Take a look at the [package page for `tmux`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tmux).  It seems that `apt-get` is looking at *wheezy* (a little old).  The [Debian releases-page](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases) shows how old: 2013 (and still being updated).

By the way, you could be running Ubuntu or some other downstream distribution rather than Debian, but it's likely there will be the same time difference.

Answer (score 2):

If using Debian stable, and you have a package you want updated, you can use backports, as seen in https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

in short: add *"deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main"* (after main, can also add contrib and non-free, if using them.)
to your sources.list, which by default is /etc/apt/sources.list

(as root, or using sudo)
update by using *apt-get update* (or *aptitude*)
Then, to use a package from backports, you need to use the command 
*apt-get -t jessie-backports* install/upgrade... (or *aptitude*)

(If using Debian wheezy, also for it backports exist)

Comment: He still cannot get 2.2 this way: [jessie has 1.9.6](https://backports.debian.org/wheezy-backports/overview/).  FWIW, none of the programs I work on have backports.

Comment: perhaps, however backports isn't from the current stable, but from testing (and rarly from unstable-mostly security updates). more importently is that [wheezy-backports](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/tmux) is 1.9-6. However, [jessie-backports](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/tmux) is 2.2-1 (both are >=1.8, which is what he is looking for) (For big programs backports may be a bad choice, but for simpler things like tmux, it works fine)